# Decode Image data in Android

Tags: javascript, java, android, swift, decode

I am confusing to decode image data in Android.

Following code is ont working. It got "bad base-64" error message.

```
String c = data.getString("profile_picture").replace("\n", "");
byte [] picture_data = Base64.decode(c, Base64.DEFAULT);  // ******** ERROR (bad base-64) *******

InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(picture_data);

BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, null, options);

ImageView _profile_image = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.image_view);
_profile_image.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

I tried all Base64.* as a decode parameter.

I have working code in Swift and Javascript with same image data(json string).

Swift

```
let _profileImageView = UIImageView()
let _profile_image: UIImage? = 
registration_data["profile_picture"].string!.urlDecode()
_profileImageView.image = _clinic_image
_profileImageView.frame = CGRect(x: 10,
                             y: 10,
                             width: _cellDetailView.frame.width * 0.2,
                             height: _cellDetailView.frame.width * 0.2
)
_cellDetailView.addSubview(_profileImageView)

public func urlDecode() -> UIImage? {
    var img: UIImage = UIImage()
    let base64String = self.replacingOccurrences(of: "}", with: "+")

    let decodeBase64:NSData? =
        NSData(base64Encoded:base64String, options: NSData.Base64DecodingOptions.ignoreUnknownCharacters)

    if let decodeSuccess = decodeBase64 {
        img = UIImage(data: decodeSuccess as Data)!
    }
    return img
}
```

Javascript

```
document.getElementById('profile_photo_preview').src = "data:image/jpg;base64," + decodeURI(encodeURI(jsondata.profile_picture))
```

What I want to do is to make the java code as same as in swift and in javascript.

I know in swift, if I remove NSData.Base64DecodingOptions.ignoreUnknownCharacters option, it didn't show image.

How can I do this?

Please give me an advice.

Comment: why are you removing `\n` from your Base64 string ?

Comment: In "NSData.Base64DecodingOptions.ignoreUnknownCharacters" document of swift, it seems to remove line ending character.

Comment: In your Swift code you shouldn't use `NSData`, use its native Swift counterpart, `Data`. Moreover, don't force unwrap `UIImage(data: decodeSuccess as Data)!`, since the fact that you could base64 decode the String doesn't necessarily mean that it can be represented as a `UIImage`, so the failable initializer can still return `nil`. It especially doesn't make sense since you're returning an optional `UIImage` anyways. `var img: UIImage = UIImage()` doesn't make sense either, since it makes your func return a non-nil `UIImage` all the time.

Comment: Thank you for advices. You must be right. But it is not my job. Swift code was written by another person. My job is to write android code that works well as same as swift and javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use encoding with

```
java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream boas = new java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream();
Bitmap bm = ((android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable) imageview1.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, boas);

byte[] imageBytes = boas.toByteArray();

String img_str = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

And decoding with

```
byte[] decoded1String = Base64.decode(img_str, Base64.DEFAULT); Bitmap decoded1Byte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decoded1String, 0, decoded1String.length);
imageview1.setImageBitmap(decoded1Byte);
```

Comment: Thank you for an advice.

But the function that encoding and upload image file is not android code. It is written by javascript and I can not rewrite this function. I have to write the code that is suitable to existing code.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. What I want to say is that there is not a function to encode and to send the server in android. The image is uploaded via to javascript function by web. In android, only I have to do is to show the image from the server.